# Area enclosed between the roots of a quadratic

Tags: calculus, integration, roots, quadratics, area

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

If $f(x)$ has roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, what is the area enclosed by $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis between $x=\alpha$ and $x=\beta$ in terms of $a,b$ and $c$?

It is also given that $\alpha>\beta.$

[image: Description of question]

If $a=1$, then I thought this might be easier since you get:

$$A=\int_\beta^\alpha{(x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+({\alpha}{\beta})x) dx}$$

But even after evaluating this, I still wasn't even able to find an answer in terms of the coefficients.

I've been at this problem for a while now, and I would love some help. Any ideas?

Comment: If $a$ is a constant, $\int af(x)\text{d}x = a\int f(x)\text{d}x$. In general, integration is something called an *inner product*. One of the properties of inner products is multiplication by constants can be pulled outside the inner product. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Basic_properties).

Comment: I don’t understand. What is the problem with doing $$\left|\int_\beta^\alpha (ax^2+bx+c)dx\right|?$$

Comment: @programjames I find the mentioning of inner products in this situation misleading. An inner product takes two inputs, whereas integration only has one input. (I know that you can build inner products using integrals, but this is not the point here). The correct notion here is that integration is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map).

Comment: If i'm right you're trying to use the fact that $f(x) = a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ however in this case you have $f(x) = ax^2 -ax(\alpha + \beta) + a\alpha\beta$ where $b = a(\alpha + \beta), c = a\alpha\beta$ from your original equation

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever seen Archemedes' proof of the quadrature of a parabola?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_of_the_Parabola

Archimedes proved that any secant through a parabola intersecting at points $\alpha, \beta$ form a region with area $\frac{a(\alpha - \beta)^3}{6}$

But using calculus...

$y = ax^2 + bx + c$

let's put this parabola into vertex form.

$y = a(x + \frac {b}{2a})^2 + c - \frac {b^2}{4a}$

Save this for later...

$\int_\beta^\alpha ax^2 + bx + c\ dx$

$\beta = \frac {-b - \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\\
\alpha = \frac {-b + \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$

let's perform a u-substitution.  $u = x + \frac {b}{2a}, du = dx$

$\displaystyle a\int_{-\frac {\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}}^{\frac {\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}} u^2 - \frac {b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}\ du$

$a(\frac 13 u^3 - \frac {b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}u)|_{-\frac {\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}}^{\frac {\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}}$

$a(\frac 23 (\frac {b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2})^\frac 32 - 2(\frac {b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2})^\frac 32) = -\frac {(b^2 - 4ac)^\frac 32}{6a^2}$

Comment: Since you've already written the vertex form for the parabola equation and mentioned Archimedes' result, I won't bother making a separate post.  We can take the "height" of the parabola segment to be $ \ \frac{b^2}{4a} - c \ > \ 0 \ $ and its width as the difference of the real roots $ \ \frac{\sqrt{D}}{a} \ \ . $  As the segment has $ \ 4/3 \ $ times the area of a triangle of equal height and base width, we obtain $$ \frac43 · \left( \frac12 · \left[\frac{b^2}{4a}-c \right] · \  \frac{\sqrt{D}}{a} \right) \  =  \ \frac23 · \frac{D}{4a} · \frac{D^{1/2}}{a} \  =  \ \frac{D^{3/2}}{6a^2} \ \ . $$

Answer (score 1):

For $x$-coordinate of the apex $\mu = -\frac{b}{2a}$, discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$, we can use the quadratic formula to obtain $\alpha = \mu + \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$, $\beta= \mu - \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$ (WLOG assuming $a>0$).

Thus, the area contained is the absolute value of the definite integral of the function from $\beta$ to $\alpha$, which is

$$\left| \int_\beta^\alpha{ax^2 +bx +c\,\mathrm{d}x}\right| = \left| \left[\frac{a}{3}x^3 + \frac{b}{2}x^2 +cx\right]_\beta^\alpha\right| = \left|\mu^2\sqrt{\Delta}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{\Delta^{\frac{3}{2}}}{4a^2}+b\mu\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{a}+c\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{a}\right|$$

$$=\left|\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a}\left(c-\frac{b^2+2ac}{6a}\right)\right|$$

Answer (score 0):

As @insipintegrator pointed it out,$$\left|\int_\beta^\alpha (ax^2+bx+c)dx\right|=|\frac{a}{3}(\alpha^3-\beta^3)+\frac{b}{2}(\alpha^2-\beta^2)+c(\alpha-\beta)|,$$
with $\alpha=\alpha(a,b,c)$ and $\beta=\beta(a,b,c)$ are very well known.

Answer (score 0):

To pursue your approach, *not* restricting the polynomial to $ \ a \ = \ 1 \ \ , $ we have
$$ A \ \ = \ \ a \int_\beta^\alpha \ \   x^2 \ - \ (\alpha+\beta)x \ + \  \alpha \beta   \ \  dx $$
[you have an extra "x" on what should be the "constant term" :  I presume that was a typo]
$$ = \ \ a·\left( \ \frac13x^3 \ - \ \frac{\alpha \ + \ \beta}{2} ·x^2 + \ \alpha \beta x \ \right) |_{\beta}^{\alpha} $$
$$ = \ \ a· \frac{2·(\alpha^3 \ - \ \beta^3) \ - \ 3·(\alpha \ + \ \beta)·(\alpha^2 \ - \ \beta^2) \ + \ 6·\alpha \beta·(\alpha \ - \ \beta)}{6} $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{a}{6}·(\alpha \ - \ \beta) · [ \ 2·(\alpha^2 \ + \ \alpha \beta \ + \ \beta^2) \ - \ 3·(\alpha \ + \ \beta)^2 \ + \ 6·\alpha \beta \ ]  $$
[applying "differences of two cubes" and "two squares"]
$$ = \ \ \frac{a}{6}·(\alpha \ - \ \beta) · ( \ 2  \alpha^2 \ + \ 2\alpha \beta \ + \ 2\beta^2  \ - \ 3 \alpha^2 \ - \ 6 \alpha \beta \ - \ 3\beta^2 \ + \ 6 \alpha \beta \ )  $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{a·(\alpha \ - \ \beta)}{6} · ( \ -  \alpha^2 \ + \ 2\alpha \beta \ - \ \beta^2   \ ) \ \ = \ \ - \frac{a·(\alpha \ - \ \beta)^3}{6} \ \ , $$
which is related to the result from Archimedes' quadrature that **Doug M** mentions.  The result is negative since your integral evaluates an area "below" the $ \ x-$axis.  So the area enclosed by the $ \ x-$axis and the parabola is the absolute-value of this, $ \ \frac{a·(\alpha \ - \ \beta)^3}{6} \ \ . \ $

As I mention in the comment to that post, the difference between the two real zeroes is $ \ \alpha - \beta \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{D}}{a} \ \ . \ $  With the vertex "below" the $ \ x-$axis, $ \ D \ = \ b^2 - 4ac \ > \ 0 \ \ , \ $ so we may at last write
$$ A \ \ = \ \ \frac{a· \left(\frac{\sqrt{D}}{a} \right)^3}{6} \ \ = \ \ \frac{( \ b^2 - 4ac \ )^{3/2}}{6·a^2} \ \ .  $$